# Can't remove a User location Icon from my MAP?

Tags: maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I am using React Native Maps from `react-native-maps` library, and I have a problem with on of the icons of the userLocation, I don't want it to show up, But it is there, the problem is when I set a property **showsUserLocation** to false to make disappear I am losing a functionality.

I will explain more with code and images, this my code :

```
<MapWrapper
        ref={this.mapRef}
        followUserLocation
        zoomEnabled
        showsUserLocation
        mapType={isSatMode ? 'satellite' : 'standard'}
        rotateEnabled={false}
      >
        {!isNilOrEmpty(markers) && !isNilOrEmpty(selectedMenuItem) && markers.map(marker => this.renderMarker(marker, handleOnClickMark))}
        {!isNilOrEmpty(polylines) && polylines.map(this.renderPolyline)}
      </MapWrapper>
```

The **showsUserLocation** is `true` now, which means that I have two icons on my Map :

- the blue Icon pointing on my location
- The icon that I can click on the move to my location ( I want to get rid of this )

With images :

[image]

When I change the **showsUserLocation** to `false`, the two of them are no longer there, but I need the blue icon on my View.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about setting showsMyLocationButton to false?

Comment: Yeah that solves it! How simple, but just couldn't find that field before. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Jarrett it was my case too, it seems like it is not used or mentionned a lot

Answer (score 3):

By setting `showsMyLocationButton` to false it works.